# Authorized calls for Azure B2C user

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to have a user login using an Azure B2C custom policy, and then use the token that is passed to the redirect URI to make authorized calls to our APIs. I'm aware that the token given after logging in is an id token, but I haven't seen a way to exchange it for an access token.

Using the id token worked for Azure API management, but not in logic apps as it expects the issuer to be login.microsoftonline.com.

Is there a way that I can exchange the user's id token for an access token, or a better way to secure endpoints so that only logged-in B2C users can access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD B2C supports both the id token and access token where id token contains claims that you can use to identify users in your application and access token are used to identify the granted permissions to your APIs.

There is no way to exchange id token for an access token, but you can request for the tokens in the request by passing id_token+token in the response_type  while authenticate the request.

```
GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=xxxx
&response_type=id_token+token
&redirect_uri=https://www.jwt.ms
&response_mode=fragment
&scope=openid%20offline_access
&state=arbitrary_data_you_can_receive_in_the_response
&nonce=12345
```